# ¿como hago para copiar los datos de una lista circular doble a otra?

Tags: c++

De antemano gracias
Mi problema a resolver es el siguiente nesecito llenar una lista circular doble con los datos de otra lista circular doble, pero al momento de pasar los datos me los sobreescribe es decir me muestra solamente de la lista donde voy a copiar los datos el ultimo dato copiado, ¿que tengo mal en el codigo?

```
struct nodo1{
    int dato1;
    nodo1* siguiente1;
    nodo1* atras1;
} *primero1, *ultimo1;

struct nodo2{
    int dato2;
    nodo2* siguiente2;
    nodo2* atras2;
} *primero2, *ultimo2;

struct nodo3{
    int dato3;
    nodo3* siguiente3;
    nodo3* atras3;
} *primero3, *ultimo3;
void complementoRonda(){
    nodo1* actual1 = new nodo1();
    nodo2* actual2 = new nodo2();
    nodo3* nuevo3 = new nodo3();
    
    actual1 = primero1;
    actual2 = primero2;
    
    if(primero1!=NULL && primero2!=NULL){
    do{
        if(actual1->dato1!=actual2->dato2){//Copiar los numeros que son distintos a los de la segunda lista
            nuevo3->dato3 = actual1->dato1; //Intento almacenarlo
        }
        if(primero3==NULL){
            primero3 = nuevo3;
            ultimo3 = nuevo3;
            primero3->siguiente3 = primero3;
            primero3->atras3 = ultimo3;
        }else{
            ultimo3->siguiente3 = nuevo3;
            nuevo3->atras3 = ultimo3;
            nuevo3->siguiente3 = primero3;
            ultimo3 = nuevo3;
            primero3->atras3 = ultimo3;
        }
            cout << "\n Nodo ingresado en la Ronda 3\n\n";
        actual1 = actual1->siguiente1;
        actual2 = actual2->siguiente2;
    }while(actual1!=primero1 && actual2!=primero2);
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero, estás confundiendo nodos con listas. No son lo mismo de la misma manera que un escalón no es una escalera:

[image]
[image]

Ni un eslabón es una cadena:

[image]
[image]

Ni una perla es un collar:

[image]
[image]

---

Segundo, dado que no estás inicializando tus datos, tu algoritmo falla desde el primer paso:

```
struct nodo1{
    int dato1;
    nodo1* siguiente1;
    nodo1* atras1;
} *primero1, *ultimo1;

struct nodo2{
    int dato2;
    nodo2* siguiente2;
    nodo2* atras2;
} *primero2, *ultimo2;

struct nodo3{
    int dato3;
    nodo3* siguiente3;
    nodo3* atras3;
} *primero3, *ultimo3;
```

Las variables `primero1`, `ultimo1`, `primero2`, `ultimo2`, `primero3` y `ultimo3` tendrán un valor indeterminado al iniciar el programa, dicho valor no será `NULL` como tampoco lo será ninguno de los miembros puntero de las instancias de `nodo1`, `nodo2` ni `nodo3`. Por lo que todas las comprobaciones que confíen en que alguno de los punteros que usas valgan (o no valgan) `NULL` fallarán. Lo raro es que no te falle el programa en tiempo de ejecución.

---

Tercero, no tienes que usar tres tipos distintos para hacer lo mismo. Todos tus nodos son iguales así que deberías usar el mismo tipo:

```
// Las llaves ({}) al final de la declaración declaran el objeto como 'vacío' que en el
// caso de los punteros significa inicializar a 'nullptr' (puntero nulo) y en el caso
// de los enteros (int) significa inicializar a cero.
struct nodo{
    int dato{};
    nodo1* siguiente{};
    nodo1* atras{};
} *primero1{}, *ultimo1{}, *primero2{}, *ultimo2{}, *primero3{}, *ultimo3{};
```

---

Finalmente, la lógica para añadir nodos a listas doblemente enlazadas es la siguiente:

1. El nuevo nodo debe enlazar su puntero anterior con el anterior nodo cabeza de lista.
2. El anterior nodo cabeza de lista debe enlazar su puntero siguiente con el nuevo nodo.
3. El nuevo nodo se transforma en la nueva cabeza de la lista.

En tu caso, las cabezas de lista son los nodos `ultimo`, así que podemos generalizarlo a una función como la siguiente:

```
// Enlaza un nuevo dato a la lista y devuelve el nodo al nuevo dato
nodo *anyade_dato(nodo *&cabeza, int dato)
{
    if (cabeza)
    {
        cabeza->siguiente = new nodo{dato, nullptr, cabeza};
        return cabeza = cabeza->siguiente;
    }
    else
    {
        return cabeza = new nodo{dato};
    }
}
```

Si además de lo anterior eliminamos las variables globales y gestionamos la memoria solicitada, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>

struct nodo{
    int dato{};
    nodo *siguiente{};
    nodo *atras{};

    ~nodo() { delete siguiente; }
};

void imprime_desde(const nodo *n)
{
    if (n)
    {
        std::cout << n->dato << ' ';
        imprime_desde(n->siguiente);
    }
}

// Enlaza un nuevo dato a la lista y devuelve el nodo al nuevo dato
nodo *anyade_dato(nodo *&cabeza, int dato)
{
    if (cabeza)
    {
        cabeza->siguiente = new nodo{dato, nullptr, cabeza};
        return cabeza = cabeza->siguiente;
    }
    else
    {
        return cabeza = new nodo{dato};
    }
}

int main()
{
    nodo *primero1{}, *ultimo1{}, *primero2{}, *ultimo2{}, *primero3{}, *ultimo3{};

    primero1 = anyade_dato(ultimo1, 0);
    primero2 = anyade_dato(ultimo2, 0);
    anyade_dato(ultimo1, 1);
    anyade_dato(ultimo2, 1);
    anyade_dato(ultimo1, 2);
    anyade_dato(ultimo2, 3);
    anyade_dato(ultimo1, 4);
    anyade_dato(ultimo2, 5);

    imprime_desde(primero1);
    std::cout << '\n';
    imprime_desde(primero2);
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Copiar los números que son distintos a los apuntados por el segundo nodo
    for (nodo *n1 = primero1, *n2 = primero2; n1 && n2; n1 = n1->siguiente, n2 = n2->siguiente)
    {
        if (n1->dato != n2->dato)
        {
            if (ultimo3)
                anyade_dato(ultimo3, n1->dato);
            else
                primero3 = anyade_dato(ultimo3, n1->dato);
        }
    }

    imprime_desde(primero3);

    delete primero1;
    delete primero2;
    delete primero3;

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes verlo funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPLbtswEDyTX7FBAb@gILHcXGI3l6J/UaBgRcYgQC1VkXSRGOqvu0uRcuVUMnxY7cw@OVs1zX1lBB4vl08aKxOkgoO2zrdK1C@ckxEqD2ilPXOm0YMU3p67PWfRBxunj0Er9GrkE74VLn5z9id6Vms4g1RGeQVX/h46HiknqyXouml1rX5I5aRaVRZdqgkbXPNY@BVWZDEymfPy@bmywcPhAHj/EhuK5hKW1AG7TUX4teKaYKrJ@cMDfEMj3gUEBAzqZPupQIChv3ZewBv1ewrKnBQok1oRZsTleVJ8E5JqkWeVPItK/FTvooBhV9f@E5CHSB@j5uALoPqdFh3DCipmTOPbAhI3rpe1yocWs4dC/kvTj8iUcSrV@RhwU6MbFhJ7rYXGVd9sGqTfYmu3566ATTBe19nOQDkCyjGwGwG7pIIhFzUw3ljOWsBjfJoh7ySpzKTJ8O00Us4iFFPOxuxmYz7Pxjyt45i30huGjkE3ml1@x6jUSXY5w@aMRPvVNlq0YKwjcUS2g1@BTsoiSFItvSJ5RI/TGZOWnToGlFnTnL3aFrJMMb7F0CE9F5b/vss9ELxYACaLVLMdSYyUGclYjk8rqa0/020@ybvESTfAerwnZGVEH5vY5q6AIUXcBctipt@gr0mBfAzrorRnlrzrXyufxuOed5fLXw)</kbd>.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su maravillosa respuesta @PaperBirdMaster