# ¿Cómo corregir el fallo en este Programa de pilas?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, pilas

PROBLEMA CON PILAS (crashea)

Debo hacer un Programa que intercambie los extremos de una pila, muestra la pila y luego deja de funcionar.

el programa deja de funcionar luego de que se muestra la pila creada por el usuario, no entiendo que es lo que lo hace fallar si alguien puede ayudarme con este problema de antemano gracias.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


typedef int DATO; // esto es exclusivo de este ejercicio no es necesario realmente

struct NODO { //ESTRUCTURA NODO
    DATO Info;
    NODO * Sig;
};

typedef NODO* ptNODO; // esto tampoco es necesario

//variables / arreglos Globales



void PUSH(ptNODO &Pila,DATO X){ ptNODO NUEVO; //METER A LA PILA sus parametros son el puntero pila y el dato que se quiere agregar
     NUEVO = new NODO; //se reserva espacio
     NUEVO->Info=X; //se llena el campo necesario con la informacion requerida 
     NUEVO->Sig=NULL; // se llena el puntero del nodo con null (si es el primero)
     if(Pila != NULL) NUEVO->Sig=Pila; // si no es el primero entonces se llena con la direccion actual del puntero pila
     Pila=NUEVO; // hacemos que pila apunte al nuevo nodo ya que este es la "cima actual" de la pila
}
bool POP(ptNODO &Pila){ // SOLO SE LE PASA EL PUNTERO PILA COMO PARAMETRO
    ptNODO A = Pila; //PUNTERO AUXILIAR QUE APUNTA AL MISMO SITIO QUE PILA
     if(A!=NULL){
        Pila=Pila->Sig;//PILA QUEDA APUNTANDO AL NODO DE ABAJO DEL QUE VAMOS A BORRAR
        delete(A); //SE BORRA EL PUNTERP AUXILIAR
        return true;
     }else return false;
}

bool CIMA(ptNODO Pila, int &XC){ 
    if(Pila != NULL){
    XC=Pila->Info;
    return true;
}else return false;
}


void F4(ptNODO &pila){ // Funcion que intercambia los extremos de una pila
    ptNODO pilaaux= NULL;
    
    int XC,cima,fondo;
    
    cima=pila->Info; //guarda la cima 
    pila=pila->Sig;
    
    while(pila!=NULL){
            CIMA(pila,XC);
            PUSH(pilaaux,XC); //guarda el contenido de la pila
            POP(pila);
    }
    
    CIMA(pilaaux,XC); //la cima de pilaaux es el anterior fondo de pila
    fondo=XC; // guarda el fondo
    
    pila->Info = cima; // nuevo fondo
    while(pilaaux!=NULL){
        CIMA(pilaaux,XC);
        PUSH(pila,XC); //al pasar el contenido de una pila a otra y luego de esa a otra queda en el mismo orden
        POP(pilaaux);
    }
    PUSH(pila,fondo); //nueva cima
    
    delete(pilaaux);
}


void SHOWPILE(ptNODO &pila){ //funcion mostrar pila
    ptNODO auxpila = pila; //se guarda la posicion de la cima de la pila
    
    while(pila!=NULL){
            cout<<pila->Info<<" , ";
            pila = pila->Sig;
    }
    pila = auxpila; // regresa el puntero pila a la cima de la pila
}

int main(){
    ptNODO pila=NULL;
    char band='n';
    int dato1;
    cout<<"\n por favor ingrese elementos en la pila en igual orden que en el enunciado \n"<<endl;
    cout<<" o ingrese los datos que desee \n"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n elementos del enunciado: 12(fondo),10,8,7,20(cima) \n"<<endl;
    do{
        cout<<"Dato Nuevo ---- >"; cin>>dato1;
        PUSH(pila,dato1);
        cout<<"\n Desea ingresar otro dato? si(Y) no(N) ---> "; cin>>band;
        
    }while((band=='y') || (band=='Y'));
    
    cout<<"\n esta es la pila ingresada \n"<<endl;
    SHOWPILE(pila);
    
    F4(pila);
    
    cout<<"\n esta es la pila luego de pasar por la funcion F4 \n"<<endl;
    SHOWPILE(pila);
    
    return 0;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: en vez de añadir spam, podrías describir con más detalle los pasos para llegar a que el programa deje de funcionar correctamente. Qué datos usas? Sale algún error en la consola?

Comment: mis disculpas como dije es mi primera ves preguntando aqui y ademas de eso voy corto de tiempo despues lo editare correctamente

Comment: Si vas corto de tiempo, imagínate como es para los voluntarios que vienen a responder preguntas gratis, mientras están trabajando en algo que les paga el alquiler. Tómate el tiempo de permitir que te ayuden ;)

Answer (score 4):

Tienes una buena cantidad de problemas serios en tu código, por suerte son problemas que ya han sido discutidos en esta página.

1. Mezclas cabeceras de [c](/questions/tagged/c) con cabeceras [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), no deberías hacerlo. [Lee este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber más del tema.
2. Incluyes cabeceras que no usas. Repasa cuál es el cometido de cada cabecera, la mayoría no las necesitas incluir. Por ejemplo, `<stdio.h>` es una cabecera de C para la comunicación con consola e `<iostream>` es una cabecera de C++ para la comunicación con consola, incluyes dos cabeceras que sirven para lo mismo y además sólo usas las funcionalidades de una de ellas.
3. Estás ocultando en un alias de tipo (un `typedef`) un puntero y tratando los nodos como si fuesen listas, eso es un disparate. Lee estos hilos:

   - [No se imprimen bien las listas doblemente enlazadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/111434/2742).
   - [Asignación de punteros en listas enlazadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/115391/2742).
   - [Concatenar dos listas simplemente enlazadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/116811/2742).
   - [Algo no funciona en mi implementación de listas abiertas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/120913/2742).
   - [¿Como lleno una multilista?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/167430/2742).
   - [Tengo una lista simplemente enlazada ¿Cómo le añado datos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/169453/2742).
   - [¿Cómo puedo Definir el Nodo Raíz de un Árbol?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/170266/2742).
   - [warning: passing argument 1 of 'HashInsertar' from incompatible pointer type](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/192263/2742).
   - [Listas dobles c++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/203326/2742).
   - [Segmentation fault C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/204421/2742).
   - [¿Como extraigo datos del final de una pila dinamica?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/205348/2742).
   - [¿Cómo eliminar elementos de una pila conservando los nodos anteriores? en c++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/240773/2742).
   - [Duda sobre el uso de Pilas en C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/274471/2742).
   - [¿como hago para copiar los datos de una lista circular doble a otra?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/490218/2742).
4. En tu código mezclas identificadores en inglés con identificadores en español, decídete por uno u otro y haz que tu código sea homogéneo y más legible.

Respecto a tu fallo, es bastante fácil de descubrir:

1. En la función `F4` Mueves los elementos de `pila` (recibida por parámetros) a `pilaaux` (variable local).

   ```
   while(pila!=NULL){
       CIMA(pila,XC);
       PUSH(pilaaux,XC); //guarda el contenido de la pila
       POP(pila);
   }
   ```
2. Cuando acaba el bucle anterior, `pila` está vacía (apunta a `NULL`).
3. Accedes a datos de `pila` (que está vacía), lo cuál provoca el fallo en tiempo de compilación.

   ```
   pila->Info = cima; // 'pila' es NULL, ¡¡BOOM!!
   ```

Si corriges ese fallo y programas como si usases C++ contemporáneo, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Pila
{
    Pila() : cima(NULL) {}
    ~Pila()
    {
        delete cima;
    }

    void Push(int dato)
    {
        if (cima)
        {
            NODO *nuevo = new NODO;
            nuevo->Info = dato;
            nuevo->Sig = cima;
            cima = nuevo;
        }
        else
        {
            cima = new NODO;
            cima->Info = dato;
            cima->Sig = NULL;
        }
    }

    void Pop()
    {
        if (cima)
        {
            NODO *anterior = cima->Sig;
            delete cima;
            cima = anterior;
        }
    }

    bool Cima(int &dato) const
    {
        if (cima)
        {
            dato = cima->Info;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    void Muestra()
    {
        for (NODO *actual = cima; actual; actual = actual->Sig)
            cout << actual->Info << ' ';
    }

    void F4()
    {
        if (NODO *base = cima)
        {
            while (base->Sig)
                base = base->Sig;

            int auxiliar = cima->Info;
            cima->Info = base->Info;
            base->Info = auxiliar;
        }
    }

private:
    // El nodo esta encapsulado en el objeto pila
    struct NODO {
        int Info;
        NODO *Sig;

        ~NODO()
        {
            if (Sig)
                delete Sig;
        }
    };

    NODO *cima;
};


int main() {
    Pila p;

    cout <<
            "\n por favor ingrese elementos en la pila en igual orden que en el enunciado \n"
            " o ingrese los datos que desee \n"
            "\n elementos del enunciado: 12(fondo),10,8,7,20(cima) \n";

    char opcion;
    do
    {
        cout << "Dato Nuevo ---- >";
        int dato;
        cin >> dato;

        p.Push(dato);

        cout << "\n Desea ingresar otro dato? si(Y) no(N) ---> ";
        cin >> opcion;

    } while((opcion == 'y') || (opcion == 'Y'));

    cout << "\n esta es la pila ingresada \n";
    p.Muestra();
    p.F4();

    cout << "\n esta es la pila luego de pasar por la funcion F4 \n";
    p.Muestra();

    return 0;
}
```